# Run a python script or .exe file from Laravel

Tags: python, php, laravel, exe

I'm designing a Laravel 9 application and I'm triying to run a python a script using exec or shell_exec I also try to use a symfony process and no one of it result. My python script is

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

from re import L
import sys
import MySQLdb

miConexion = MySQLdb.connect( host='127.0.0.1', user= 'root', db='pruebas' )
cur = miConexion.cursor()
mySqlInsert = "INSERT INTO documentFin (co, localizacion, categoria, idItem, nombre, cantidad, fecha, lote) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"

def insertarTabla(co, localizacion, categoria, idItem, nombre, cantidad, fecha, lote):
    val = (co, localizacion, categoria, idItem, nombre, cantidad, fecha, lote)
    try:
        cur.execute(mySqlInsert, val)
        miConexion.commit()
    except:
        print(val)
def verificarFecha(fecha):
    if(len(fecha) == 10):
        if(fecha[4] == "/" and fecha[7] == "/"):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False


def probar():
    with open("UCIN3053.p01") as archivo:
        lines = archivo.readlines()
    co = ""
    localizacion = ""
    categoria = ""
    contadorMas = 0
    matriz = []
    listaTemp = []
    for x in range(len(lines)):
        temp = lines[x].split()
        if(len(temp) > 1):
            if(temp[1] == "C.O."):
                co = temp[3] + " " + temp[4]
            elif(temp[1] == "Localizacion"):            
                local = temp[3:len(temp) - 1]
                
                
            elif(temp[1] == "Categoria"):
                categoria = temp[3] 

            if(temp[0].isnumeric()):
                if(temp[1].isnumeric()):
                    listaTemp.append(cod)
                    listaTemp.append(cadena)
                    listaTemp.append(temp[1])
                    listaTemp.append(temp[0])
                    listaTemp.append("")
                    matriz.append(listaTemp)
                    listaTemp = []
                elif(verificarFecha(temp[1])):
                    listaTemp.append(cod)
                    listaTemp.append(cadena)
                    listaTemp.append(temp[2])
                    listaTemp.append(temp[0])
                    listaTemp.append(temp[1])
                    matriz.append(listaTemp)
                    listaTemp = []
                else:
                    listaTemp.append(temp[0])
                    cod = temp[0]
                    cadena = ""
                    for x in range(1, len(temp)):
                        if(temp[x].isnumeric() and (temp[x + 1] == "UND" or temp[x + 1] == "FCO" or temp[x + 1] == "CJA" or temp[x + 1] == "FRA")):
                            numTemp = x
                            break
                        cadena += temp[x] + " "
                    listaTemp.append(cadena)   
                    listaTemp.append(temp[numTemp])
                    listaTemp.append("") 
                    listaTemp.append("")     
                    matriz.append(listaTemp)
                    listaTemp = []
            elif(temp[0] != "|"):
                if(temp[0][len(temp[0]) - 2]) == "-":
                    if(verificarFecha(temp[1])):
                        listaTemp.append(cod)
                        listaTemp.append(cadena)
                        listaTemp.append(temp[2])
                        listaTemp.append(temp[0])
                        listaTemp.append(temp[1])
                        matriz.append(listaTemp)
                        listaTemp = []
                    else:
                        listaTemp.append(cod)
                        listaTemp.append(cadena)
                        listaTemp.append(temp[1])
                        listaTemp.append(temp[0])
                        listaTemp.append("")
                        matriz.append(listaTemp)
                        listaTemp = []
        elif(len(temp) == 1):
            contadorMas += 1
        if(contadorMas == 4):
            contadorMas = 0
            for w in range(len(local)):
                localizacion += local[w] + " "

            #Añadir matriz e identificadores
            for x in range(len(matriz)):
                insertarTabla(co, localizacion, categoria, matriz[x][0], matriz[x][1], matriz[x][2], matriz[x][3], matriz[x][4])
            matriz = []
            localizacion = ""
    cur.close()
probar()
```

And my Controller in Laravel is

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
    use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;
    
    class InventarioController extends Controller
    {
        public function reportar(Request $request){
            $file = 'C:/Users/edwin/Documents/lectordocs/lectorDocs.exe';
            if(file_exists($file)){
                // echo 'File does exist  ::   ' . $file;
                $process = new Process([$file]);
                $process->run();
    
                // executes after the command finishes
                if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
                    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
                }
    
                return redirect()->to("/login");
    
                }
            else{
                return redirect()->to("/home");
            }   
        }
    }
    <?
```

Those returns are my form on debugging and I obtain this error INTERNAL ERROR: cannot create temporary directory! I also use the route C:\xampp\htdocs\Login\login-laravel\public\assets\python but it also give me the same error.

Anynone now what I can do?